# Error while loading vector from Glove in Spacy

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, stanford-nlp

I am facing the following attribute error when loading glove model:

Code used to load model:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
tokenizer = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', disable=['tagger','parser', 'ner', 'textcat'])
nlp.vocab.vectors.from_glove('../models/GloVe')
```

Getting the following atribute error when trying to load the glove model:

```
AttributeError: 'spacy.vectors.Vectors' object has no attribute 'from_glove'
```

Have tried to search on StackOverflow and elsewhere but can't seem to find the solution. Thanks!

From pip list:

- spacy version: 3.1.4
- spacy-legacy 3.0.8
- en-core-web-sm 3.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `spacy init vectors` to load vectors from word2vec/glove text format into a new pipeline: https://spacy.io/api/cli#init-vectors

Answer (score 1):

`spacy version: 3.1.4` **does not** have the feature `from_glove`.

I was able to use `nlp.vocab.vectors.from_glove()` in `spacy version: 2.2.4`.

If you want, you can change your spacy version by using:

`!pip install spacy==2.2.4` on  your Jupyter cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I have a lot of other dependencies on spacy. So changing to 2.2.4 creates additional errors. Is there another way to call the from_glove feature in 3.1.4 version?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think you can call `glove` from `spacy 3`.

Comment: May be just use `spacy 2`  for glove and again update to `spacy 3` for your other dependencies. Just a suggestion.